# AWS S3 Object Access and Editing

Tags: amazon-web-services, awss3transfermanager, amazon-s3

Let's say I wanted to store a hashset object into a bucket on AWS S3. Can I frequently update that object(adding new strings to the hashset) with ease, or would I have to actually pull the hashset out of the bucket before I can make changes to it?

Comment: If it's your intention to store the entire hashset in a single S3 object then no, this won't work. You cannot update an S3 object in place, you can only replace it (entirely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 is a key -> (Object+Metadata) store. Recently, (Dec 2020), S3 has gained strong consistency on update, delete, list and get. Only buckets have eventual consistency constrain. This means you should be able to store serialized objects on S3 with ease and use basic CRUD operation to read, update, delete and list stored objects.

So, yes, in theory you will be able to store a hashset on S3. You can possibly map individual value-hashes of the set to s3 key suffixes and store values in S3 directly. You will not have to load the entire hashset into memory as you can map most of the operations directly to S3.

1. HashSet::Put -> S3::PutObject. O(1)
2. HashSet::isPresent -> S3::GetObjectMetaData.  O(1)
3. HashSet::Remove -> S3::DeleteObject.  O(1)
4. HashSet::ListAllObjects -> S3::ListObjects.  O(n)

You might be able to implement union, intersection operations as well. Though, I am not sure how efficient it might be compared to usual implementations.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Is there anywhere I can possibly find some documentation describing how I might go about mapping the operations directly to S3 without having to load the entire hashset?